# Problemas desde ayer para subir apps a Apple

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes

Buenos días,

desde ayer está dando un error supuestamente de servidor al subir las aplicaciones. Es un problema de Apple? o es algo mío?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: Yo tuve el mismo error hace unos días. ahora parece que están los servidores bien (Lo puedes comprobar aquí: https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/). Inténtalo de nuevo y si no te funciona prueba a reiniciar el XCode ya que hay algunas veces que se queda "pillado".

Comment: Gracias Francisco, pero parece ser que ha vuelto el error aunque support este todo OK, he hablado con ellos y por lo que me comentan están con ello pero está así desde ayer por la noche y me parece mucho tiempo la verdad.